# How update ag-grid data when TreeData feature is used

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

ag-grid documentation provides 2 features Tree Data and Data Update:

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0
- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0

But I don't understand how am I supposed to perform Data Update over Tree Data

Example:
I have following javascript data:

```
const tvSeries = [
  {
    season: "Season 1",
    episodes: [
      {episode: "s1e1"},
      {episode: "s1e2"},
      {episode: "s1e3"},
      ]
  },
  {
    season: "Season 2",
    episodes: [
      {episode: "s2e1"},
      {episode: "s2e2"},
      {episode: "s2e3"},
      ]
  }
]
```

And set it to grid via

```
 gridApi.setRowData(tvSeries)
```

Each season will be grouping row with children rows - its episodes

Now I want to add new episode to first season, so I do

```
tvSeries[0].episodes.push({episode: "s1e4"})
```

**How should I notify grid about this change?** If I call
 *gridApi.setRowData(tvSeries)* one more time - entire grid will be redrawn, it's sloppy and not cool. There are useful method

```
gridApi.updateRowData(rowDataTransaction: RowDataTransaction)
```

but I cant understand how to describe tree changes in RowDataTransaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is impossible to partially update data when using TreeData feature.

Restriction #1: InMemoryNodeManager contains guard which prohibit updating group set (add/remove/update groups):

```
public updateRowData(rowDataTran: RowDataTransaction): RowNodeTransaction {
    if (this.isRowsAlreadyGrouped()) { return null; }
    ...
}
```

Restriction #2: RowRenderer.redrawRows don't force children refresh for redrawn groups. So if children subset is changed, grid will never be aware of it

Both restriction leads to a situation, when neither top-level groups can't be partially updater, not their children. The only method left for developer is **gridApi.setRowData()** which reloads entire grid.